# Mostrar cuadro de diálogo para escoger Launcher en Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Intento mostrar el siguiente cuadro de dialogo, algunos de los launchers más conocidos en opciones tienen la opción de poder escoger el launcher por defecto, se abre un cuadro de dialogo con la lista de los posibles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso lo siguiente:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent );
```

Y solo hace cerrar mi aplicación sin mostrar ningún diálogo ni error, es decir se va de la pantalla.

¿Cómo se puede llamar?

Comment: Revisa los filtros para los intent implicitos. Me paso lo mismo.  Si en algun momento seleccionastes "always", busca como deshacerlo. De cualquier manera revisa este vinculo -> https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html?hl=es-419